# Print Vec<i32> in rust with a custom formatter

Tags: rust

I have the following:

```rust
{
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
{
  println!("v = {}", v);
  let first = &v[0];    
  println!("The first element is: {}", first);
}

v.push(6);

{
  println!("v = {}", v);
  let first = &v[0];    
  println!("The first element is: {}", first);
}
}
```

And my error is:

```rust
  println!("v = {}", v);
                     ^ `Vec<{integer}>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
`Vec<{integer}>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Vec<{integer}>`
```

That seems straightforward.  I will follow the error message and implement the fmt interface for a vector of integers, as suggested:

```rust
use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Display for Vec<integer>{
    fn fmt(&self) {
        for i in self.iter() {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }
}

let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
{
  println!("v = {}", v);
  let first = &v[0];    
  println!("The first element is: {}", first);
}

v.push(6);

{
  println!("v = {}", v);
  let first = &v[0];    
  println!("The first element is: {}", first);
}
```

Which tells me it cannot find 'integer'

```rust
impl fmt::Display for Vec<integer>{
                          ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
cannot find type `integer` in this scope
help: you might be missing a type parameter

<integer>

impl fmt::Display for Vec<integer>{
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
impl fmt::Display for Vec<integer>{
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Vec` is not defined in the current crate
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
```

Isn't integer already imported?

Well, fine.  Instead of integer, let's do it generically. But this /also/ fails for

```rust
// This doesn't work because first is borrowing an element of v.  So I can't modify v after.
use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Display for Vec<T>{
    fn fmt(&self) {
        for i in self.iter() {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }
}

let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
{
  println!("v = {}", v);
  let first = &v[0];    
  println!("The first element is: {}", first);
}

v.push(6);

{
  println!("v = {}", v);
  let first = &v[0];    
  println!("The first element is: {}", first);
}
```

How does rust print a vector of integers?

Comment: Wouldn't the debug format `{:?}` be satisfying?

Comment: Hmm, I think yes it would, but now that I am down this rabbit hole, I am curious how to do it with a proper printer?

Comment: Note that `integer` is the compiler’s way of saying “we recognize your integer literal(s) and are acknowledging that their type is somewhat up in the air”. It’s not a real type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way would be to use the debug formatter `{:?}` instead of the display formatter `{}`.

However, if you really want your custom formatter for a vector, then you cannot do it directly.
In Rust, when you implement a trait for a type, the trait or the type (or both) must come from your crate.
In your attempt, both `Display` and `Vec` come from `std`.

The usual workaround is to use the newtype pattern: you define your own type which just wraps an existing one.
In order to ease the access to the inner type, we can implement `Deref` and `DerefMut`.

Please find a simple example below.

```rust
use std::{
    fmt::{Display, Formatter, Result},
    ops::{Deref, DerefMut},
};

struct VecProxy<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> Deref for VecProxy<T> {
    type Target = Vec<T>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<T> DerefMut for VecProxy<T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

impl<T: Display> Display for VecProxy<T> {
    fn fmt(
        &self,
        f: &mut Formatter<'_>,
    ) -> Result {
        for i in self.iter() {
            writeln!(f, "~~> {}", i)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = VecProxy(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    {
        println!("v = {}", v);
        let first = &v[0];
        println!("The first element is: {}", first);
    }

    v.push(6);

    {
        println!("v = {}", v);
        let first = &v[0];
        println!("The first element is: {}", first);
    }
}
/*
v = ~~> 1
~~> 2
~~> 3
~~> 4
~~> 5

The first element is: 1
v = ~~> 1
~~> 2
~~> 3
~~> 4
~~> 5
~~> 6

The first element is: 1
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. There are two issues here:

One, there is no `{integer}` type in Rust. If you write a integer literal, like `0`, you could mean for it to be one of many different types. It will typically be inferred based on later usage (or sometimes can default to `i32`), but until then, and if an error needs to reference a integer type that has not-yet-been deduced, you'll see `{integer}`. You may also see `{float}`.

Two, you cannot implement implement `Display` for `Vec`. If you attempt it, the compiler will emit an error like:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate
 --> src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
5 | impl Display for Vec<T> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------
  | |                |
  | |                `Vec` is not defined in the current crate
  | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
  |
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

This is due to Rust's "orphan rules" that restrict what traits can be implemented for which types to preemptively reject potentially conflicting implementations  and aid in trait-lookup.

---

To print a `Vec<_>` with a custom implementation, you'll need to use the newtype idiom that wraps a `Vec` and implements `Display` on that new type instead:

```
struct MyFormat(Vec<i32>);

impl Display for MyFormat {
    // ...
}
```